# How to pass action string for commandButton using f:attribute tag in Composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm developing composite component in JSF. In that I can pass method names as arguments in following way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="noOfButtons"  type="java.lang.Integer" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="actionOnly"  type="java.lang.Boolean" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="myBean" required="true" type="com.jsf.CRUDBean"/>
        <composite:attribute name="myIcons"  type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="myAction" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="myDesc" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>

    </composite:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>

            <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{cc.attrs.noOfmys - 1}" var="counter"
                varStatus="status">

                <h:commandButton id="myButton_${counter}"
                    action="#{cc.attrs.myBean[fn:split(cc.attrs.myAction, ',')[status.index]]}"
                    image="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/#{fn:split(cc.attrs.myIcons, ',')[status.index]}"
                    title="#{fn:split(cc.attrs.myDesc, ',')[status.index]}"
                    style="padding:2px">
                <p:spacer width="5px;" />
            </c:forEach>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

This is working perfect.But in my case, I need to pass action in following way.

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="#{cc.attrs.noOfmys - 1}" var="counter"
                varStatus="status">

                <h:commandButton id="myButton_${counter}"

                    image="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/#{fn:split(cc.attrs.myIcons, ',')[status.index]}"
                    title="#{fn:split(cc.attrs.myDesc, ',')[status.index]}"
                    style="padding:2px">
                        <f:attribute name="action" value="#{cc.attrs.myBean[fn:split(cc.attrs.myAction, ',')[status.index]]}" />

            </h:commandButton>

                <p:spacer width="5px;" />
            </c:forEach>
```

But this is not working in my application. Whenever I click commandButton from the page nothing happening at user level. Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Is there any other way to achieve this in JSF?

Comment: Sorry for that @BalusC. Even I didn't get the business logic. I just got instructions about what I have to do.